# Dynamic text for humanoid avatar

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, text-to-speech, avatar

I am new to game development, i used iclone character avatar and added some basic animations, text to speech, facial animation.

I bring all my avatars, animations to Unity3d Via 3dxchange, only the text to speech audio file can't be imported to Unity 3d.

My questions is possibly i can use the iclone audio file in Unity 3d,
I entered a text manually in Iclone for the avatar to speak, where that audio file is saved in Iclone?

My goal is to create a humanoid avatar which able speaks & read the text entered by the user with facial expression and some body gesture.

Is it possible to achive facial expression and lib sync adjustments in Unity 3d??

Its possible to do facial expression and lib sync adjustments in iclone , blender or any other tools?

Needs some direction, help or any tutorials for how to proceed for read the text entered by the user with facial expression and some body gesture.

Thanks

Comment: Text to speech in unity 3d is the right direction??

Comment: Hi cloudVision, I wonder if iClone (and 3dxchange) helped you do real-time facial animation and speech? I am trying to implement verbal behavior in a Unity mecanim character. Please see this post: [link](http://forum.reallusion.com/268216/Unity-mecanim-skeleton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Unity store for TTS Plugins also try CrazyTalkAnimatior may be meets your requirement.

http://www.reallusion.com/crazytalk/animator/animator_trial.aspx